# Inline SVG containing mask renders incorrectly

Tags: html, svg

Inline two slightly modified versions of the same SVG in the same HTML. Configure them to appear in different situations by using `display: none;` and other modes, like `display: flex;` or `display: block;` etc.

Notice how only the one added to the markup first behaves correctly.

See demo of the issue here:
https://codepen.io/sbnc_eu/pen/GRZwaaM

(Note: this is not the most efficient way to achieve such hover effect, however it is only created for demo purpose, simplified from a more complex problem.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when SVGs are added to the HTML inline, the IDs defined within become IDs defined in the context of the HTML. Therefore if two slightly modified version is inlined without changing the IDs, the first one added will take the given ID in the HTML context, and any other inline SVGs referring to the same ID would refer to the first element with that ID.

This can create an issue especially with masks, as masks are usually referenced by an ID inside an SVG.

The issue may not be apparent even if an SVG is inlined in the HTML multiple times, provided they all use the same mask under the same ID. The resulting HTML is technically invalid (due to ID duplication), but the SVGs may appear fine. However if for any reason the first SVG containing the mask with a given ID is made invisible (e.g. using `display: none;`) the mask will become dysfunctional.

Morale of the story: when inlining SVGs (or any other markup for that matter) always make sure elements have unique IDs in the context of the resulting HTML, not only inside the inlined element.